# NSMutableData to NSString give nil

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am using my app NSURLConnection for getting webpage of a site.

this how i call the NSURLConnection

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://jokes.moment.co.il/default.asp?s1=4&s2=0"];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:request delegate:self];
```

this is how i append the data that i get:

```
-(void) connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{
    if (receivedData)
    {
        [receivedData appendData:data];
    }
    else 
    {
        receivedData = [[NSMutableData alloc] initWithData:data];
    }
}
```

and this is how i try to convert it to NSString:

```
-(void) connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
    NSString *string = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:receivedData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
}
```

the receivedData is 47586 bytes and when i do the convert the string is nil

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A quick look at the content for your URL show that the content-type is ISO-8859-1

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1"/>
```

Try changing your call to initWithData to...

```
[[NSString alloc] initWithData:nsdata encoding:NSISOLatin1StringEncoding];
```

Answer (score 1):

More likely than not, the received string is not validly encoded as NSUTF8StringEncoding.

You may need to write the string to the filesystem and then use one of the NSString methods that describes any conversion errors via an `NSError**` argument to know the exact error.